# Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and SQL DB and deploy to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

Folks,

I am trying to perform steps given on below link

[Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and SQL DB and deploy to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/)

While doing so I lost on step #11. Which Says

*Select Create new server, enter a server name, user name, and password.
The server name must be unique. It can contain lower-case letters, numeric digits, and hyphens. It cannot contain a trailing hyphen. The user name and password are new credentials you're creating for the new server.
If you already have a database server, you can select that instead of creating one. Database servers are a precious resource, and you generally want to create multiple databases on the same server for testing and development rather than creating a database server per database. However, for this tutorial you only need the server temporarily, and by creating the server in the same resource group as the web site you make it easy to delete both web app and database resources by deleting the resource group when you're done with the tutorial.
If you select an existing database server, make sure your web app and database are in the same region.*

and below to this there is an image

[image]

I am not sure how this popup will open up. I tried the steps multiple time but don't know where is "Create new server" button/link. This link is not available on previous step(step #10).

I am using VS 2013 Update 5.

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply from the same post that steps given in documents are from two different SDK and mine was the latest one and it has some changes. They are working on updating document.

Reply,

> The App Service tools were updated and this article is in the process
>   of being updated. If you're on Azure SDK 2.8.1 or higher, you can
>   create a new SQL Server and database via the Services tab in the new
>   experience. Essentially this document is mixing screenshots from 2
>   different SDK versions, and we're working with Rick Anderson
>   [riande@MSFT] to get the article updated so that it reflects only the
>   experience in the post-SDK 2.8.1 UI. Apologies for the confusion here.